# Azure SDK Python,I want to assign multiple ports to an NSG Security Rule

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to manipulate Azure security groups in Python.
The big picture works.

But,Attempts to add a rule to an existing security group.

```
network_client.security_rules.create_or_update('resourcesname',"nsg-name","secure-name",SecurityRule(
        protocol='Tcp', 
        source_address_prefix='*', 
        destination_address_prefix='*', 
        access='Allow', 
        direction='Inbound', description=name+' use rules',source_port_range='*', 
        #destination_port_range="1000,2000",
        #destination_port_range=["1000","2000"],
        destination_port_range=[1000,2000],
        priority=100, name="secure-name"))
```

I get the following error when I specify multiple ports

```
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: SecurityRuleInvalidPortRange
Message: Security rule has invalid Port range. Value provided: [1000,2000]. Value should be an integer OR integer range with '-' delimiter. Valid range 0-65535.
```

I've also tried string arrays and simple strings.
But it fails.
Can anyone solve the problem?

Comment: as per the recommendation in the error did you try to define the destination port range as per below? `destination_port_range=[1000-2000]` What happened if you did the above?
can you share if you are getting an error with the above syntax?

Comment: Tried." 1000-2000" or 1000 will succeed. But the target port is not continuous.

Comment: @user14020029, please see the answer below, it works.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I can't press Up because I'm not strong enough...I'll press it when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's quite simple.

If you want to add a range of ports, you should use the property `destination_port_ranges` instead of `destination_port_range`(**Note** the "s" at the end of the 2 properties).

Here is my code:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.v2020_04_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup, SecurityRule

subscription_id = 'xxx'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = 'xxx',
    secret = 'xxx',
    tenant = 'xxx'
)

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

network_client.security_rules.create_or_update('xxx',"yysecurityGroup","my_Port_8080",SecurityRule(
        protocol='Tcp', 
        source_address_prefix='*', 
        destination_address_prefix='*', 
        access='Allow', 
        direction='Inbound', description='my_Port_8080 use rules',source_port_range='*', 
        #destination_port_range="1000,2000",
        destination_port_ranges=["1000","1005","2005","2020"],     
        priority=100, name="my_Port_8080"))


print("**complete**")
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: It's great. You have saved my life!! You're safe.